# Overclocked Intel Core 2 Duo E4300, what now?

Tags: temperature, overclocking, intel-core2, cpu-speed

I have overclocked Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E4300 CPU. I changed FSB from 200 to 220.
Multiplier is x9. The old core speed was 9 x 200 = 1800 GHz. Now it's 1980 GHz.

I runed memtest to 20 passes and everythink is fine. The temperature was about ~58C on 1.8 GHz, now it's ~63C. Are these temperatures okay, if not then what should I do:

1)change CPU fan speed

2)or overclock back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go higher if you need the additional speed...  63C is normal for that processor in fact you were running a little cooler the the normal temp before Overclocking. According to the [Intel](http://www.overclock.net/t/154939/faq-core-2-duo-temp-guide) page 61.4 degrees is normal for the Tcase (just make sure you monitoring temps on the cpu and not the cores and you should be seeing the Tcase temp). This post on [Overclockers.net](http://www.overclock.net/t/154939/faq-core-2-duo-temp-guide) is a great guide for Temperature monitoring on the Core2. However what you do next is really up to you, your temps are fine and since mem test cleared it looks like you are doing everything right.

Comment: What is the highest temperature for this CPU?

Comment: Hmm I don't actually have technical reference for max temps and it's been a while since I had a Allendale/Conroe chip. Personally I feel you should be safe up to 70C. I wouldn't personally take it any higher, but feel free to experiment. If you find that your stable at 70C and want to push it a little further try it... Just make sure you go up slowly in very small increments. And don't neglect your Vcore as you raise the FSB, 1.3525 is your max on the vcore according to intel. However overclockers states you can get to 1.488 on air with a chance of instability.